# How do I configure Nagios mobile / SMS alerts?

Tags: nagios, sms

How do I send alerts from Nagios monitoring tool to mobile?

Any resources or links or tutorials are fine.

Answer (score 8):

The following describes how alerts can be sent directly to SMS, without using e-mail. Basically, you need to connect a GSM modem (or a suitable mobile phone) via USB, then send your text messages directly via the GSM network.

- http://matt.bottrell.com.au/archives/205-Nagios-2-way-alerting-via-SMS-Part-2.html

If you want a much simpler solution and are comfortable using e-mail (such that if your internet connection goes down, you will not get alerts on your cell phone), just send alerts to your phone's e-mail address:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways

Comment: The first link died, and i don't see how to do the latter suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The March 2010 issue of Linux Journal has an article titled [Using an SMS Server to Provide a Robust Alerting Service for Nagios](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10605)

They use the MultiTech Systems MultiModem iSMS Intelligent SMS server, and explain in great detail how they got it up and running. As well as all the scripts and configuration they wrote.

Definitely worth a read.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

SMS messages can be send by using a GSM modem (hardware option) or using a web based service. Nagios exchange has a list of available options http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Notifications

**Shameless plug:**
At [OpsGenie](http://www.opsgenie.com), we've recently implemented support for sending Nagios alerts to iPhone/iPad and Android devices using push notifications in addition to sending notifications via email and SMS. Description of the integration is on our support site [How to configure Nagios for OpsGenie](http://support.opsgenie.com/customer/portal/articles/780193-nagios-integration).

Answer (score 3):

I personally opt for hardware solutions. They have such advantage over internet sms gateway services, that they work even if your Internet connection is broken (firewall, router, internet connection is down).

Have a google search on sms hardware gateway. These kind of devices usually offer you a HTTP API which can be used for easy integration with Nagios.

I personally can say that [SMSEagle device](http://www.smseagle.eu) is worth to take look.

Beside API for sending/receiving SMS they also have a functionality for monitoring services/servers.

Ready-to-use Nagios plugin: https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Notifications/SMS/SMS-Notifications-and-Alerting-via-SMSEagle/details

Answer (score 2):

You could use email to sms

Comment: This of course only works as long as your network is up. One of the reasons I use nagios is to tell me when this isn't the case anymore.

Comment: No, that's exactly not what one should do for SMS notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to try this: http://www.alertwoo.com

It sends out SMS alerts when you receive emails from Nagios. You don't receive any configuration, they just convert your emails received from Nagios and send them as SMS text message to you in seconds.

It works great. Try it.

Comment: Please sum up the link - websites can go down for any number of reasons and the asker will be left without an answer.

Answer (score -1):

An another solution exist : TeamTILT for Nagios.

A great advantage is the heartbeat functionnality ! If your server or your mail service is down, the TeamTILT platform notifies you by SMS…

An another advantage is the number of media types : SMS, Voice call, iPhone push, email, fax, …

Just have a look here : http://www.alarmtilt.com/en/manage-your-nagios-alerts-with-teamtilt.html

;) !

Answer (score -3):

RTFM - really. The nagios documentation and online resources will help you. To get started, maybe begin at: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/notifications.html

There are a myriad of possible solutions to your problem, so you need to decide by yourself what's appropiate for you. Just one hint: Use a REAL modem or GSM module. Don't rely on online SMS services.