# recommendations for SMS gateway to use with Nagios

Tags: nagios, sms-gateway

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I configure Nagios mobile / SMS alerts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/164565/how-do-i-configure-nagios-mobile-sms-alerts)

does anyone have any recommendations for an SMS gateway to use with Nagios? I'm looking to setup SMS alerting from our existing Nagios server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [googlecl](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/). The notification string sets an event (at 2 minutes after the current) in google calendar with SMS reminder (configured to be sent in a minute before the event). That's how I get notification in a minute after something happens.

But this is not the best way. If something happens with Internet connection, you will not get a notification. It's better to attach a cell phone to your nagios server and send SMS via it.

Comment: Have you done this with a cell phone before?  What model?  Any concerns about signal quality in a datacenter?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Quick googling gave me this project: http://www.gnokii.org/docs.shtml

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I want to avoid using our internet connection so that should a network outage occur it doesn't also cut off our alerting system. So I guess a cell phone or SMS gateway is the way forward for us. So the question is what hardware have people used and would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of complications over billing when using an aggregator for such messages - most won't be interested unless you're going to push a significant volume of messages. HUB's suggestion of using googlecl was a new one on me - probably because the service is only available in the US (and I'm not).

Most mobile phones now support the extensions to the Hayes AT command set for SMS functionality - certainly any modern Nokia phone will. The only problem is how you manage contention and queuing of messages - I'd previously used BSD lpd for this but you could set up a daemon to monitor a queue or a filesystem socket or a mailbox to get messages to send. It's fairly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If price is a concern, consider an alternate approach:

Set up two or more nagios sites, that monitor each other through the internet.  If one goes down, you will get alerts from the other site.  As long as they are connected through different internet paths, each can respond in the event of a failure on one or the other.

That way, you can use email to send SMS messages through phonenumber@vtext.com (Verizon) or phonenumber@txt.att.net (AT&T).

Comment: Those two email to text services won't work for most of the world.

Comment: But for the parts of the world they do work for, they work well.  Have you checked if your provider has a similar email to text service?  The examples I provided were intended as a starting point for you to explore your own cell provider's services.